# Using VNC without unlocking the lock screen locally

Tags: fedora, gnome, vnc, remote-desktop

Currently I use VNC to connect to a virtual desktop on my Fedora workstation, which for the most part works fine.  But ideally I'd like to connect to my active session on the workstation and access the apps/docs that are already open.  I can do this easily enough, but I'm concerned about local console security - ie, the lock screen unlocks and anyone walking past now has access to my workstation.

Is there a way to connect to my Fedora 23 workstation running Gnome 3.16.2 and access my active session and all open apps/docs without the lock screen unlocking locally?  Like RDPing into a Windows machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VNC Server: Disable local screen when remote VNC client connects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111418/vnc-server-disable-local-screen-when-remote-vnc-client-connects)

Comment: For the record, I think these questions are different, because the linked question is fine with creating a new session. This question refers to joining an existing session.

Comment: @Sparhawk exactly, Crunched have you ever resolved it?