# Can I lock the screen of a remote computer and still keep it visible to the others on its side, but keep it unlocked to me on my side?

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop, screen-lock, xpra

I would like to  accessing a remote computer via xpra or vnc or some other desktop sharing way, and

- on the site of the remote machine , I would like to  lock the screen (and optionally make it  visible),
- on my side, I want to keep it unlock and visible to me, so that I can still   work on it

I would like to know  both ways to make the screen of the remote computer visible and invisible on its site.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible [dupe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246507)? (Although that question has no answer either.)

Answer (score 2):

What about `xtrlock`?

> xtrlock locks the X server till the user enters their password at the
>   keyboard.
>
> While  xtrlock is running, the mouse and keyboard are grabbed and the
>   mouse cursor becomes a padlock.  Output displayed by X programs, and
>   windows put up by new X clients,  continue to be visible, and any new
>   output is displayed normally.
>
> The  mouse and keyboard are returned when the user types their
>   password, followed by Enter or Newline.  If an incorrect password is
>   entered the bell is sounded.  Pressing  Backspace or  Delete  erases 
>   one  character of a password partially typed; pressing Escape or Clear
>   clears anything that has been entered.
>
> If too many attempts are made in too short a time further keystrokes 
>   generate  bells  and are otherwise ignored until a timeout has
>   expired.
>
> The  X  server  screen saver continues to operate normally; if it
>   comes into operation the display may be restored by the usual means of
>   touching a key (Shift, for example)  or  the mouse.

On my Debian system, it's in the repositories:

```
sudo aptitude install xtrlock
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to not just lock the screen and make it still visible on the machine, but also be able to remotely work on it both unlock and visible to me using vpn or xpra. Can xtrlock allow me to do that?

Comment: I have updated my post to clarify more.